# SQL MAX function strange behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle

Stackoverflow, hello.
Having the following problem.
Suppose having a query that returns the following :[image: a query]

When I try  "select max(col1), max(col2)" on it, it returns me:

[image]

Whent I try "select max(col2),max(col1)" it returns me:

[image]

Do you have any ideas of what is happening here?

The query that gives the problem is

```
select max(col2),max(col1)
from (

SELECT 
        NVL(IS_IN_OPEN_BR, 0)                             AS col1,
        NVL(IS_IN_OPEN_ISR, 0)                            AS col2
      FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT PRD_DEV_CODE AS DEV_CODE_ISR,
          PRD_GRP_CODE               AS GRP_CODE_ISR,
          1                          AS IS_IN_OPEN_ISR
        FROM ATL_ADM.PRODUCT PRD
        INNER JOIN ATL_ADM.SB_REQ SR
        ON PRD.PRD_ID = SR.SBR_PRD_ID
        INNER JOIN ATL_ADM.LIB_REPLENISH_REQ LSR
        ON LSR.LSR_ID         = SR.SBR_LSR_ID
        WHERE LSR.LSR_STATUS <> 'CLOSED'
        GROUP BY PRD_DEV_CODE,
          PRD_GRP_CODE
        ) ISR
      FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT PRD.PRD_DEV_CODE DEV_CODE_SHIP,
          PRD.PRD_GRP_CODE AS GRP_CODE_SHIP,
          NVL( MAX (SHP.SHIP_SHIPDATE), MAX (SHP.SHIP_UPDDATET)) LAST_SHIP_DATE
        FROM ATL_ADM.SB_REQ SR
        JOIN ATL_ADM.SHIPMENT SHP
        ON SR.SBR_ID = SHP.SHIP_SBR_ID
        JOIN ATL_ADM.PRODUCT PRD
        ON PRD.PRD_ID        = SR.SBR_PRD_ID
        WHERE SR.SBR_TYPE    = 'FLA'
        AND SHP.SHIP_STATUS IN ('SHIPPE', 'MANDEV')
        GROUP BY PRD.PRD_DEV_CODE ,
          PRD.PRD_GRP_CODE
        ) SHIPS ON DEV_CODE_ISR = DEV_CODE_SHIP
      FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                PRODUCT.PRD_DEV_CODE  DEV_CODE_BR,
                PRODUCT.PRD_GRP_CODE GRP_CODE_BR,
                1 IS_IN_OPEN_BR
            FROM ATL_ADM.PRODUCT
            JOIN ATL_ADM.SB_REQ
            ON PRODUCT.PRD_ID = SB_REQ.SBR_PRD_ID
            JOIN ATL_ADM.REQT_SET
            ON REQT_SET.REQTS_ID = SB_REQ.SBR_RS_ID
            JOIN ATL_ADM.BRIEF
            ON BRIEF.BR_ID = REQT_SET.REQTS_BR_ID
            WHERE BRIEF.BR_STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('CLOSED', 'CANCEL')
            GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRD_GRP_CODE,
            PRODUCT.PRD_DEV_CODE,
            BRIEF.BR_STATUS_CODE
        ) BRS ON DEV_CODE_BR = DEV_CODE_SHIP)
```

Comment: Show us the SQL queries, I have [no problems](http://pastebin.com/zq2gFd2v) with it

Comment: More than the SQL queries, can you please provide a complete environment that demonstrates this behaviour, including table DDL, insert statements and SQL queries. In the event of no one being able to reproduce it's likely someone will need to see certain database parameters.

Comment: I have tested, no such results

Comment: @Ben, I can not give more data :(

Comment: What's your database version? I have seen problems with optimizer query rewrites on queries with FULL OUTER JOIN. Most of those problems were fixed when we upgraded to 11.2. Sometimes you can avoid the optimizer query rewrite by doing something like SELECT MAX(col2), MAX(col1) FROM (SELECT * FROM (<your query>) WHERE ROWNUM >= 1)

Comment: @KimBergHansen I also thing , that the problem is in optimizer. The database version is 11.2. Unfortunately "WHERE ROWNUM >= 1" didn't work

Comment: The FULL OUTER JOIN is rewritten internally to Oracle syntax using some UNION ALL. What I have seen is that some other rewrites like predicate pushing have gone wrong when combined with the FULL OUTER JOIN rewrite. But I have not had any cases since we got to 11.2. I can only suggest doing a trace on both your queries (the one with col1 first and the one with col2 first) and see access plan differences in the tkprof output. Then make a support case where you upload the traces.

Comment: Kindly let me know what is the result of this select max(col1||col2) and max(col2||col1) for the mentioned case of 0 0 and 1 1

Comment: As result I had overcome this problem by using a temporary table. I consider the problem in query optimizer, but taking into account the difficulty of the query and its explain plan I couldn't find the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: why do you need both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in your query

Comment: There is no point in having both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this hint:

```
select /*+ no_query_transformation */
          max(col1), max(col2)
from  ( ....
```

Without it the Oracle optimizer will attempt to guess your intention and refrase the sql for better performance.

With complex queries using inline performance views like this one it will often take the wrong guess.